# How can I invert image colors with the Python API?

Tags: python, scripting, image

I need to invert an image programmatically.
However, the command:

```py
bpy.ops.image.invert(invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
```

fails with

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.image.invert.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

According to this page
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html
there are only two possible values for "Image Context": `edit_image` and `edit_mask`. And the first one worked for me.

```py
bpy.ops.image.invert({'edit_image': bpy.data.images['texture_name']}, invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True))
```

Or the currently recommended way (without a deprecation warning):

```py
with bpy.context.temp_override(**{'edit_image': bpy.data.images['texture_name']}):
    bpy.ops.image.invert(invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
```

Probably, the same technique can be used with other image operators, and `edit_image` allows us to "select" an image we want to edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Maybe a bit easier to read, instead of unpacking a dictionary inside the arguments : `with bpy.context.temp_override(edit_image=bpy.data.images['texture_name']):` does the same thing

Answer (score 3):

```
import bpy

image = bpy.data.images.get(name) # name = image.name
override = bpy.context.copy()
override["edit_image"] = image
bpy.ops.image.invert(override, invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon a `numpy` implementation that doesn't require using an operator :
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208589/86891

```
import bpy
import numpy

def invert(image, invert_r = False, invert_g = False, invert_b = False, invert_a = False):
    pixels = numpy.empty(len(image.pixels), dtype=numpy.float32)
    image.pixels.foreach_get(pixels)
    if invert_r: 
        pixels[0::4] = 1 - pixels[0::4]
    if invert_g: 
        pixels[1::4] = 1 - pixels[1::4]
    if invert_b: 
        pixels[2::4] = 1 - pixels[2::4]
    if invert_a: 
        pixels[3::4] = 1 - pixels[3::4]
    image.pixels.foreach_set(pixels)

image = bpy.data.images["Untitled.png"]
invert(image, invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
image.update()
```